# Wso2 Esb and apache2 connection issue

Tags: apache, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Hi am working with wso2esb 4.9.0 and apache2 proxy pass to call my esb service,so basically a service request goes to Apache2 proxy pass and it redirects the call to ESB server and once the request gets completed connects get closed.

When there is any wrong data passed to the request ESB throws error and the request does not get completed but as per the synapse.properties file configuration these connections will to be closed in 3 mins

Below error logs in apache and esb:

ESB log:

```
WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-7 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
```

Apache Log:

```
[Tue Jul 04 13:41:39.814054 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28612] (20014)Internal error: [client 127.0.0.1:38838] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server localhost:8282
[Tue Jul 04 13:41:39.831567 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 28612] [client 127.0.0.1:38838] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /services/GetAlertMessageMobile2.0
```

After 12-15 days of run time ESB servers get hanged and doesn't process any request, when i restart the esb server it it will be back to normal state.

How to identify what is causing these problem

I have got some JMX attributes of the ESB server as below

```
 [EsbMonitoring] ***************** StatisticsView Attributes *********************
 [EsbMonitoring] Server Status            :RUNNING
 [EsbMonitoring] Avg Response Time        :103.19162114723454
 [EsbMonitoring] Min Response Time        :3.0
 [EsbMonitoring] Max Response Time        :180990.0
 [EsbMonitoring] Total Fault Count        :0
 [EsbMonitoring] Total Request Count      :10700010
 [EsbMonitoring] Total Response Count     :10700010
 [EsbMonitoring] ***************** Transport http Attributes *********************
 [EsbMonitoring] Sender Stats---------------------
 [EsbMonitoring] Active threads           :0
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsReceiving          :10
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsSending            :9
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsReceiving        :62
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsSending          :0
 [EsbMonitoring] QueueSize                :0
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesSent             :26961506
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesReceived         :26961361
 [EsbMonitoring] Receiver Stats-------------------
 [EsbMonitoring] Active threads           :0
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsReceiving          :43
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsSending            :0
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsReceiving        :3
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsSending          :0
 [EsbMonitoring] QueueSize                :0
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesSent             :10707854
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesReceived         :10726684
 [EsbMonitoring] ***************** Transport https Attributes *********************
 [EsbMonitoring] Sender Stats---------------------
 [EsbMonitoring] Active threads           :0
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsReceiving          :0
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsSending            :0
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsReceiving        :0
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsSending          :0
 [EsbMonitoring] QueueSize                :0
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesSent             :10778116
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesReceived         :10778116
 [EsbMonitoring] Receiver Stats-------------------
 [EsbMonitoring] Active threads           :0
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsReceiving          :0
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsSending            :0
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsReceiving        :0
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsSending          :0
 [EsbMonitoring] QueueSize                :0
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesSent             :0
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesReceived         :0
 [EsbMonitoring] ***************** Thread Attributes *********************
 [EsbMonitoring] TotalWorkerCount                 :0
 [EsbMonitoring] DeadLockedWorkers                :null
 [EsbMonitoring] AvgBlockedWorkerPercentage       :0.0
 [EsbMonitoring] Last8HourBlockedWorkerPercentage :0.0
 [EsbMonitoring] Last24HourBlockedWorkerPercentage:0.0
 [EsbMonitoring] ***************** PassThroughConnections http Attributes *********************
 [EsbMonitoring] Sender Stats--------------------------------
 [EsbMonitoring] ActiveConnections                :110
 [EsbMonitoring] Last24HourConnections            :43826
 [EsbMonitoring] LastHourConnections              :1797
 [EsbMonitoring] Last15MinuteConnections          :464
 [EsbMonitoring] Receiver Stats------------------------------
 [EsbMonitoring] ActiveConnections                :66
 [EsbMonitoring] Last24HourConnections            :9365
 [EsbMonitoring] LastHourConnections              :346
 [EsbMonitoring] Last15MinuteConnections          :92
 [EsbMonitoring] ***************** PassThroughConnections https Attributes *********************
 [EsbMonitoring] Sender Stats--------------------------------
 [EsbMonitoring] ActiveConnections                :0
 [EsbMonitoring] Last24HourConnections            :0
 [EsbMonitoring] LastHourConnections              :0
 [EsbMonitoring] Last15MinuteConnections          :0
 [EsbMonitoring] Receiver Stats------------------------------
 [EsbMonitoring] ActiveConnections                :8
 [EsbMonitoring] Last24HourConnections            :6207
 [EsbMonitoring] LastHourConnections              :333
```

Above stats are when the server is stable i just want to know if any of these help me in solving the issue.

Comment: Set proxy to http1.0. Wso2Esb has issues with keep-alive.

Comment: Hi simar are you taking about <property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2"/> or some thing else related to http1.0, and what sort of issues are in esb for keep live can you please explain in short if possible

Comment: Some time ago had something same. ESB behing nginx. It was solved on nginx to confiure nginx proxy as http 1.0. Don't remember exactly, but nginx or esb didn't release connection (keep-alive) for 3 minutes(timeout). At some moment ESB start to respond slow.

Comment: ok ill try this apache proxy http 1.0 chages.

Comment: Hi @simar can you please check with this issue hope you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409839/waiting-threads-issue-in-wso2esb